# ASP.NET MVC app authentification via REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am building a new ASP.NET MVC 5 web application. Instead of using standard forms authentication with user data stored in MS SQL, I would like to authenticate via REST API (it uses OAuth2 with bearer tokens). Are there any existing solutions or best practices on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already achieved for you. It works out of the box if you create a webapi2 project with the Individual User Accounts option selected for Authorization.

[Here's a walk through on using it.](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above you will have some help out of the box if you create a new Web API project. What's used behind the curtain is called [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity). It uses bearer tokens for the authentication and can be made available as a HTTP API via ASP.NET Web API. The user data will be stored in MS SQL Server via Entity Framework, but there are also some ports where you can use other database systems, like MySQL or MongoDB, instead.